# GR limit with massless particles and strong fields

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics

What the mechanics arises if to take limit of general relativity with massless particles interacting with strong fields? Suppose there a system of attracting particles that have zero rest mass. What would be their interaction in GR? Can they form stable orbits around each other?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10759/2451

Comment: Either this question makes no sense, or the answer is the post-Newtonian formalism.  If it's the latter, then the answer is yes, because the zeroth order term in PPN  is Newtonian gravity.

Answer (score 2):

> What the mechanics arises if to take limit of general relativity with massless particles interacting with strong fields? Suppose there a system of attracting particles that have zero rest mass. What would be their interaction in GR?

This is standard GTR with the restriction that the energy-momentum tensor is of the "pure radiation" (aka "null dust") form
$$\begin{eqnarray*}T^{\mu\nu} = \Phi^2 k^\mu k^\nu, &\;\text{where}\;& k_\mu k^\mu = 0\end{eqnarray*}.$$
This could, but need not, arise from a Maxwell field, and represents radiation in lightlike direction $k$. Since the trace is $T = 0$, the Ricci curvature is also $R_{\mu\nu} = \Phi^2 k_\mu k_\nu$ in units of $8\pi G = c = 1$. Thus, any spacetime whatsoever with Ricci curvature in this form satisfies your condition, the most trivial case being a vacuum (having zero radiation intensity), e.g., Schwarzschild spacetime

If $k$ is a geodesic field and a Killing field, then it is automatically twist-free and the field equations are reducible to a system of two-dimensional Poisson equations. Then either the solution is a $pp$-wave ($k_{\mu;\nu} = 0$) and can be put in the form
$$\mathrm{d}s^2 = -H(u,x,y)\mathrm{d}u^2 - 2\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v + \mathrm{d}x^2 + \mathrm{d}y^2$$
for any smooth function $H$, or else ($k_{\mu;\nu} \neq 0$) it can be put in the form
$$\mathrm{d}s^2 = x^{-1/2}(\mathrm{d}x^2+\mathrm{d}y^2) - 2x\mathrm{d}u\left[\mathrm{d}v + M(x,y,u)\mathrm{d}u\right]$$
where $(xM_{,x})_{,x}+xM_{,yy} > 0$. The simplest nontrivial example of the latter case is the van Stockum dust.

For details, additional constraints for Maxwell fields, and other conditions, see *Exact Solutions of Einstein's Field Equations* by Stephani, et al.

> Can they form stable orbits around each other?

If that means a stable closed orbit, then I don't know. I suspect not, but can't prove it in general.

Comment: What happens if other fields also affect such massless particle besides gravity? My question was motivated by a preon model where preons were taken to be massless but actively interacting.

Comment: Having only massless particles constrains the $T^{\mu\nu}$ to have a certain form, but is otherwise agnostic about how they interact, and so can include other non-gravitational interactions. I don't think anything more can be said in the general case, but having forces other than gravity has may make stable (non-gravitational) lightlike orbits. But I'm not familiar with how preons are supposed to work, sorry.